# Can't resolve 'lodash/fp - google map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use this library:

https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react

but when I run my project I got this error message:

```
ERROR in ./~/google-map-react/lib/google_heatmap.js
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash/fp' in '/Users/sm_emamian/Desktop/react js/shadyab/node_modules/google-map-react/lib'
[0]  @ ./~/google-map-react/lib/google_heatmap.js 6:10-30
[0]  @ ./~/google-map-react/lib/google_map.js
[0]  @ ./~/google-map-react/lib/index.js
[0]  @ ./app/components/detail/TermsOfUse.js
[0]  @ ./app/containers/Detail.js
[0]  @ ./app/routes/index.js
[0]  @ ./app/app.js
```

my package:

```
"lodash": "^3.10.1",
"google-map-react": "^0.34.0",
```

Comment: use latest version of lodash , i faced same issue with older versions -  4.17.5

Comment: https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/issues/558

Comment: try 'npm i -S lodash' then run project again